# Call to WCF service and threads running at client & service end

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf

I'm sending custom header from Silverlight application to the WCF service over HTTPS.  Through the custom header, I'm sending client's CultureInfo to the WCF service and expecting the response from service in the language of the culture I have sent. I have applied custom behaviors to both client and service ends correctly by implementing `IEndpointBehavior`, `IClientMessageInspector` and `IDispatchMessageInspector`.

I'm assuming that the the thread on which the call to service is made would be the same running at service end. i.e. the thread running the `AfterReceiveRequest` would be the same as the thread running the actual server code. Is it correct? If I set the CultureInfo of the thread to what I want, will I get the response from the service using the same culture?

(I have hosted wcf service on my local IIS. For testing purpose, I set CultureInfo on the thread to Swedish culture but the response is always in American English (which is my computer's culture language.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, the thread running the `AfterReceiveRequest` would be the same as the thread running the actual server code.

When I set the culture on the thread in the `AfterReceiveRequest`method of the class which implements `IDispatchMessageInspector`, it's set correctly.